# the result of Image.plot in Fields using R looks very bad

Tags: r, csv, field, heatmap

```
library(MBA)
library(fields)

data <- read.csv(file="Test.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

rawdata <- data.frame(as.numeric(data$X), as.numeric(data$Y), as.numeric(data$Z))

mba.int <- mba.surf(rawdata, 400, 400, extend=T)$xyz.est

fields::image.plot(mba.int)
```

and this is how the results comes up

[image]

Why is that happening ?, why is it so small on the vertical axes ?
Also would anyone know how to get rid of the white background aswell ? I would like to take this heatmap and overlay it on top of a map.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the mba.surf function

```
n = 1, m = 2
```

m initial size of the spline space in the hierarchical construction along the y axis.
If the y axis is k times the length of the x axis, m = 1, n = k is recommended.
The default is m = 1.

Comment: Acctually as i change m to a higher number than 2, it seems to be increasing the vertical axis, but only the same size is shown for example this is the image when i set m = 5 , http://i.imgur.com/1j4eWJs.png